# Show Specific Categories On Magento Home Page

Tags: category

Hope someone can help me with this. I need to show 3 specific categories on my Magento home page. I have created a "list-homepage.phtml" file and have the following code in this file

```
<?php foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?>
<?php $open = $this->isCategoryActive($_category); ?>
<?php
$cur_category=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
$layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
$layer->setCurrentCategory($cur_category);
if ($immagine = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getImageUrl()):
?>
<div class="catalog-image">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category)?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $immagine ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getCurrentCategory()->getName()) ?>" class="img-responsive" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And I have added this block to my home page in the back-end

```
{{block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.category" template="catalog/category/list-homepage.phtml"}}
```

The problem with this is that it displays all the categories I have, I just want to display 3, what do I have to do in order to achieve this?

Many Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

You can put these widgets right into the content section of your homepage, I think it shows all products in the category without paging and you can choose list/grid mode.  You just need to add it 3 times, once for each of the 3 category ids you want to include.

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" category_id="73" mode="list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this page in Google looking for a similar solution. This is the working solution I eventually came up with. Hope it helps the next person looking for how to achieve this!

**1. Create a Static Block with the following code:** 
Note: You would want to change the ids accordingly. I named my block *home-categories*.

```
{{block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.category" template="catalog/category/teaser.phtml" ids="4,3,5"}}
```

**2. In your template create a file teaser.phtml**
Location: /frontend/default/{your-template}/template/catalog/category/teaser.phtml

**3. Insert the following code in teaser.phtml**

```
<?php
    $catIds = explode(',', $this->getIds());

    $categories = array();
    foreach($catIds as $catId) {
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId); 
    $categories[$category->getName()] = array(
        'url' => $category->getUrl(),
        'img' => $category->getThumbnailUrl()
    );
}

ksort($categories, SORT_STRING);
?>
<ul class="categories">
    <?php if($category->getIsActive()): ?>
    <?php foreach($categories as $name => $data): ?>
        <li>
            <div class="imageWrapper">
            <a href="<?php echo $data['url']; ?>" title="<?php echo $name; ?>" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>">
                <span class="name"><?php echo $name; ?></span>
                <span class="image"><img src="<?php echo $data['img']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>" /></span>
            </a>
            </div>
        </li>   
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

**4. Open up your template and call the block in the location you want.**
For example in home.phtml, note that *home-categories* is the name you gave to the static block in step 1.

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('home-categories')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that all categories are returned via the function `getStoreCategories`. What you can do is create a widget that allows you to select your categories and then loads just the selected ones in the template.

Either that or a "quick" hacky fix you could add the ids directly in the template.

I would also suggest using a collection rather than a direct load.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response, could you let me know how to create the widget and call this widget to display?

Comment: Try reading through http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-magento-widget-part-1

Comment: Not really sure what to do, I am a bit lost to be honest!

Comment: Their is an option to insert a category link widget in my home page, but I need it to display an image. I found this here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302897/how-to-display-category-page-in-magento

Comment: Someone has suggested the below this - You'll need to stop the loop from completing the iteration if the current category is not wanted. One way you could do this is to note the ID of the 3 categories and use them to skip the loop iteration: code<?php 
  $arr_cat_ids = array('2','4','6'); //array of wanted category ids
  foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category):
    $this_cat_id = $_category->getId();
    if(!in_array( $this_cat_id, $arr_cat_ids)) continue; //if category is unwanted, skip to next iteration
    ....
?> - But I am not sure where I need to put this code in my orig code

Answer (score 0):

Please add custom attributes using the following code.

```
$this->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::ENTITY, 'display_category_home', array(
'group'         => 'General Information',
'input'         => 'select',
'type'          => 'text',
'label'         => 'Display category homepage',
'backend'       => '',
'visible'       => true,
'required'      => false,
'visible_on_front' => true,
'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
'source' => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
));
```

Based on the custom field setting we display the category on the home page.

```
 $_categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addIsActiveFilter() ;
foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
    <?php
    $cur_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
    $immagine = $cur_category->getImage();

    if($cur_category->getDisplayCategoryHome()) :
        ?>
        <li class="item item-<?php echo $i++;?>">
            <h3 class="transform  cat-title font-20 letter-spacing"><?php echo $cur_category->getName();?></h3>
            <a href="<?php echo $cur_category->getUrl()?>" class="links">
                <?php if($immagine) :?>
                    <img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('addpeople_subcategory')->resizeImg($immagine,Mage::getStoreConfig('addpeople_tab_subcat/addpeople_subcategory/category_image_width'),Mage::getStoreConfig('addpeople_tab_subcat/addpeople_subcategory/category_image_width')); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($cur_category->getName()) ?>" />
                <?php else :?>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="<?php echo $cur_category->getName()?>">
                <?php endif ;?>
            </a>
            <a href="<?php echo $cur_category->getUrl();?>" class="view-button transform font-20 letter-spacing">
        <span>
            View Details
        </span>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Please click to download an extension using the above code.
https://www.pearlbells.co.uk/display-selected-categories-home-page-magento-extension/