# How to show Specific categories in magento in homepage

Tags: magento-1.9, category

Like I have different categories , I want to show different specific categories in homepage.I want to show specific categories like

```
{{block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.category" category_id="4" template="catalog/category/list-homepage.phtml"}}
```

I google a lot but not found the exact solution.Please help me.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use `list.phtml` rather than using a custom file

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" category_id="15" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Do white-list that block from backend if you are on 1.9.2.2

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieve by many ways. you can add some specific attribute for the category in admin and you can display only those categories by filter that custom attribute in category collection and can able to display on home page.

Or if you just want to do it by giving a static ids of category this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/43246/show-specific-categories-on-magento-home-page) will help you.